# How can I create multiple pages dynamically for a questionnaire app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and I need to complete the following project:

I need to create a questionnaire that has the following hierarchy: sections, categories and questions. A sections must be like pages and each one has categories and each category questions. Something like this: http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2014/03/thoughts-on-xamarin-for-ios-development.html.

Someone knows how I can create a dynamic layout to do it?
Thanks

Comment: This is pretty trivial to do, but difficult to do well.  What have you tried, or what specific part of it are you stuck on?  As written your question is too broad to write a concise answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've created all the back end and methods to get all the info that I need. However, I am stuck now. If I create a drawer I need to create pages, and supposed to be dynamically. I would like to create pagination to sections and at the end finalize the questionnaire and submit.

Comment: var newpage = new ContentPage();  var layout = new StackLayout();  layout.Children.Add(... create page elements here ...);  newpage.Content = layout;

Comment: Thanka again. I have mounted my sections in a View Model and after I would like to create pages for it.  `public InspectionViewModel(string inspectionsID)
        {
            var result = GetInspection(inspectionsID);
            menuItems = new List<PagesSectionItemModel>();

            foreach (var item in result.TemplateModel.Sections)
            {
                menuItems.Add(new PagesSectionItemModel
                {
                    SectionID = item.SectionID,
                    SectionName = item.SectionName
                });
            }

        }`

Comment: Now I need to create a page according to my dynamic Menu and link each other. You now, different detail pages for each item on the menu. Could you help me, please??